# SQL: Sum the results of a query by group

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I just started learning SQL a few days ago and I am working with some basic examples. In this example I want to find trainings that my friends and teammates like (based on how many of my friends liked the training, how many friends completed the training, and the average rating from my friends on the training). So far I used sub-queries to get me a weighted value for each type of weighted value per training. I want to sum the weighted values for each training giving each training a total and then order the training list by the total and select the top few from that.

Here is what I did.

```
SELECT training_id, (5* COUNT()) AS [value]FROM progress
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT friend_id AS user_ids FROM friendships WHERE user_id=6 UNION SELECT user_id FROM membership WHERE team_id IN (SELECT team_id FROM membership WHERE user_id = 6))
AND completed = 1
GROUP BY training_id

UNION ALL

SELECT training_id, (10 * AVG(rating))
FROM reviews
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT friend_id AS user_ids FROM friendships WHERE user_id=6 UNION SELECT user_id FROM membership WHERE team_id IN (SELECT team_id FROM membership WHERE user_id = 6))
GROUP BY training_id

UNION ALL

SELECT training_id, COUNT()
FROM likes
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT friend_id AS user_ids FROM friendships WHERE user_id=6 UNION SELECT user_id FROM membership WHERE team_id IN (SELECT team_id FROM membership WHERE user_id = 6))
GROUP BY training_id
```

The results look like:

```
training_id     value
______________________
1                10
2                5
1                34.5
2                45
1                6
2                3
```

Please let me know if you know of a way to do this or if there is an alternative to this method that I should be looking at.

(the tables 'likes' 'reviews' and 'progress' all contain the field "training_id". What do you think about Joining the three tables to begin with?)

Comment: Maybe walk before you run

Comment: What database are you actually using? What is the desired output?

Comment: Why don't you use the SUM() function to some all the values?

Comment: Post some sample data.

Comment: Question is tagged mysql, sql-server and sqlite. Which are you actually using?

Comment: So you want to add up the three values per ID, such as to get ID 1=50.5, ID 2 = 53?

Comment: Oh my bad. I thought the language was 90% similar between all the SQL's   I don't really know the difference between them. I build and test using sQLite and then transfer the controllers and models to the server using SQL server. Also, this query pulls from 8 tables of data and I really didn't feel like writing them all out. Took me less time to just solve it. (I'm a front end developer going through the learning curve of back end development, its not easy, but thanks for all your help, especially Thorsten!)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite impressive. Your query is well structured and easy to read. If you want sums per training_id, simply build an outer query upon your own:

```
select training_id, sum(value)
from (<your query here>) x
group by training_id
order by sum(value) desc;
```

As to joining the tables: No, generally you don't want to do this. You don't want to join each progress record with each review record and each likes record per training_id. This would multiply your values (e.g. 2 progress entries, 3 reviews, and 4 likes for one training would give you 2 x 3 x 4 = 24 intermediate records). In your specific case this would do no harm, as `AVG` would result in the same value and you'd replace `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(DISTINCT progress_id)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT likes_id)`, but once you'd use `SUM` you're in trouble.

What you could do is join the aggregates:

```
with mates as
(
  select friend_id as user_id from friendships where user_id = 6
  union 
  select user_id from membership where team_id in 
               (select team_id from membership where user_id = 6)
)
select 
  training_id, 
  coalesce(p.value, 0) + 
  coalesce(r.value, 0) + 
  coalesce(l.value, 0) as total
from
(
  select training_id, 5 * count(*) as value
  from progress
  where user_id in (select user_id from mates)
  and completed = 1
  group by training_id
) p
full outer join
(
  select training_id, 10 * avg(rating) as value
  from reviews
  where user_id in (select user_id from mates)
  group by training_id
) r using (training_id)
full outer join
(
  select training_id, count(*) as value
  from likes
  where user_id in (select user_id from mates)
  group by training_id
) l using (training_id)
order by 2 desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, thank you for your input. I was right on my second hunch. I needed to use Joins. I only read about Joins in the documentation and wasn't familiar with them, but once I tried it, it was pretty straight forward.

Here is the solution.

`SELECT training.*, ((10 * AVG(reviews.rating)) + COUNT(DISTINCT likes.user_id) + ( 5* COUNT(DISTINCT progress.trainee_id))) AS total
FROM training
JOIN likes
ON training.training_id = likes.training_id
JOIN reviews
ON training.training_id = reviews.training_id
JOIN progress
ON training.training_id = progress.training_id
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT friend_id AS user_ids FROM friendships WHERE user_id=6 UNION SELECT user_id FROM membership WHERE team_id IN (SELECT team_id FROM membership WHERE user_id = 6))
AND progress.completed = 1
AND progress.trainee_id IN (SELECT friend_id AS user_ids FROM friendships WHERE user_id=6 UNION SELECT user_id FROM membership WHERE team_id IN (SELECT team_id FROM membership WHERE user_id = 6))
ORDER BY total DESC
GROUP BY training_name
LIMIT 6`

This gave me
training_id, training_name, total --these are the field names of the result
1, Beginner LiveCode, 53
2, SQL 101, 48